# Convert Request to string or json (HttpRequestWrapper )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to convert entire request object to string for write in text file for future reference. I am trying with below code, but getting errors.

Code:

```
string lsRequest = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Request);
```

or

```
string lsRequest = Request.toString();
```

[image]

Comment: You need to serialize each property of Resource Object.You can do something like this    var headers = Request.Headers.ToString();
similarly you can serialize for other properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

A circular reference is when an object contains itself (or contains and object which contains the parent etc). Therefore, the serializer fails to serialize it.

You can attempt to save only the properties of the object you really need to reconstruct the request

In ASP.Net you can work with sessions, which may archive what you want to do
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net